# Java equivalent of System.Xml.XmlNode.InnerXml

Tags: java, .net

Is there a java equivalent of .NET's `System.Xml.XmlNode.InnerXml`?

I need to replace some words in an XML document.

I cannot use Java's `org.w3c.dom.Node.setTextContent()` because this removes the XML nodes.

Thanks!

Source:

```
<body>
<title>Home Owners Agreement</title>
<p>The <b>good</b> thing about a Home Owners Agreement is that...</p>
</body>
```

Desired output:

```
<body>
<title>Home Owners Agreement</title>
<p>The <b>good</b> thing about a HOA is that...</p>
</body>
```

I only want text in `<p>` tags to be replaced. I tried the following:

```
replaceText(string term, string replaceWith, org.w3c.dom.Node p){
       p.setTextContent(p.getTextContent().replace(term, replaceWith));

}
```

The problem with the above code is that all the child nodes of `p` get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the solution.

The key to this is that you don't want to replace the text of the actual node. There is a actually a child representation of just the text. I was able to accomplish what I needed with this code:

```
private static void replace(Node root){
    if (root.getNodeType() == root.TEXT_NODE){
        root.setTextContent(root.getTextContent().replace("Home Owners Agreement", "HMO"));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){ 
        outputTextOfNode(root.getChildNodes().item(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [jdom](http://www.jdom.org).

Something like `document.getRootElement().getChild("ELEMENT1").setText("replacement text");`

You have a little bit of work to do in converting the document into a JDOM document, but there are adapters that make that fairly easy for you. Or, if the XML is in a file, you can just use a JDOM Builder class to create the DOM that you want to manipulate.
`

Comment: Wouldn't I still lose the child elements in ELEMENT1 if I did that?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? I'm finding it hard to visualise the XML you are attempting to change.

Comment: updated the question with an example. The problem is that child nodes are lost when using p.setTextContent()